# Não faz o parse do bootstrap datepicker para dd/mm/yyyy - 400 Bad Request (POST)

Tags: java, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, datepicker

Eu tenho uma aplicação web, basicamente roda puro com JSP + AngularJS.

O template que uso do bootstrap, não tinha *datepicker* com AngularJS, então estou usando com jQuery.

Eu tenho em minha tela, um modal com vários campos, eu JÁ conseguia passar todos os dados através de uma requisição POST com AJAX para meu controller Java, **não dava erros.**

Quando adicionei o datepicker, começou a dar o erro 400. O que eu percebi é que a data está sendo passada para meu controller java como `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Eu fiz a tratativa com a opção `format` do *datepicker*, antes de enviar as datas para o POST ser executado.

O que eu já fiz:

- `format` do *datepicker* já sendo setado como `dd/mm/yyyy` e `pt_BR`, mesmo assim não funfa.
- já verifiquei meu DTO para ver se o que está sendo passado na requisição tem o mesmo tipo (`DATE` no caso).
- Conferi meus imports, conforme vi em alguns posts relacionados atenção com a sequência do import.

Galera, não sei mais o que fazer, parece algo tão simples. Se precisarem que poste mais código, só falar. .

```js
BoxApp.controller("UsuariosController", function($scope, $http) {   

    $scope.usuarios={};
    $scope.usuariosParaAlterar={};

    $scope.iniciar = function() {
        $http.get('/boxmlV2/usuario').success(function (response) {
            $scope.usuarios = response;
        });
    };
    $scope.iniciar();

    $scope.setSelected = function(selecao){
        $scope.usuariosParaAlterar = selecao;
    };

    /**
     * Trecho para validar o form ao submeter.
     */
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submitForm = function(formUsuarios) {
        $scope.submitted = true;        

        if (formUsuarios.$valid) {
            $("#dataValidadeConta").datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',                
                language: 'pt-BR'
            });
            $("#dataValidadeSenha").datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',                
                language: 'pt-BR'
            });     
            $scope.editaUsuario();
        }
    };

    $scope.editaUsuario = function() {      

        $http.post('/boxmlV2/usuario/salvarUsuario', {
            ativo : $scope.usuariosParaAlterar.ativo, 
            idUsuario : idUsuario.value,
            nome : nome.value,
            senha : senha.value,
            email : email.value,
            bloqueado : $scope.usuariosParaAlterar.bloqueado,
            dataValidadeConta : $scope.usuariosParaAlterar.dataValidadeConta,
            dataValidadeSenha : $scope.usuariosParaAlterar.dataValidadeSenha, 
            resetSenha : $scope.usuariosParaAlterar.resetSenha,
            perfil : $scope.usuariosParaAlterar.perfil          
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.sucesso();
        }, function(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });

    };

    $scope.sucesso = function() {
        $scope.closeMyPopup();
        $scope.iniciar();       
    };

    $scope.closeMyPopup = function() {
        $(myModal_autocomplete).modal('hide');
    };



});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Data Validade Conta:<span
        class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input
            class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium date-picker"
            name="dataValidadeConta" id="dataValidadeConta"
            ng-model="usuariosParaAlterar.dataValidadeConta" size="16"
            type="text" value="" required /> <span class="help-block">
            Selecione a data </span> <span style="color: red"
            ng-show="submitted && form.dataValidadeConta.$error.required">Campo
            Data Validade Conta Obrigatório.</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Data Validade Senha:<span
        class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input
            class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium date-picker"
            ng-model="usuariosParaAlterar.dataValidadeSenha"
            name="dataValidadeSenha" id="dataValidadeSenha" size="16" type="text"
            value="" required /> <span class="help-block"> Selecione a
            data </span> <span style="color: red"
            ng-show="submitted && form.dataValidadeSenha.$error.required">Campo
            Data Validade Senha Obrigatório.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: debug chrome]

Java Controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class CadastroUsuariosController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/usuario", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView iniciar(ModelMap modelMap){
        return new ModelAndView("usuario");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/usuario",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody List<UsuarioDTO> obterTodos(ModelMap modelMap){
        return usuarioService.obterTodos();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/usuario/salvarUsuario", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody RetornoDTO insereOuEditaUsuario(
            @RequestBody UsuarioDTO usuarioDTO) {

        usuarioService.insereOuEditaUsuario(usuarioDTO);
        return new RetornoDTO(RetornoEnum.SUCESSO);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resumindo, mexendo no .js do componente bootstrap (components-date-time-pickers.js, o que não é aconselhável), dava pra formatar corretamente a data, mas o problema não era esse, quando estava fazendo meu POST pelo ajax, ali pegando as datas pelo scope, estava passando o objeto todo e não um valor, como o .value faria se não fosse um datepicker.

Solução paliativa: Eu fiz passar a string da data ".toString()" pro meu controller java, lá no meu DTO eu recebi como string também e trabalhei com o SimpleDateFormat pra formatar a data corretamente pro banco aceitar a inserção.

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando SpringMVC e precisa dizer a ele qual o formato de data esperar para esse campo do seu model.

É possível fazer isso de forma simples e específica para o campo usando a seguinte [anotação](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) no atributo do seu modelo:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Ou pode fazer o mesmo em nível de controlador adicionando o seguinte método ao controller:

```
@InitBinder
private void binders(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

Este é um mecanismo para definir formatos arbitrários de entrada. Veja [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou aplicar e retorno...

Comment: Luiz, só uma pergunta, ali no meu JS eu estou fazendo a conversão já pra ir pro meu controller. Sabe porque não funciona? por favor, não entendo pq.. também estava tentando forçar no cabeçalho do header pt-BR no Accept-Language

Comment: @leonardo Tudo que vc precisa fazer é mandar e receber no mesmo formato. Independente de qual formato é enviado pelo javascript, use o mesmo no servidor e tudo vai dar certo. Não precisa se preocupar com a localidade.

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo dessa forma, no meu modelo em cima do atributo adicione essa anotação.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Na classe main

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new FixedLocaleResolver(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
}
```

E no meu input utilizo dessa forma

```
<input id="dataNascimento" type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{dataNascimento}"
data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-language="pt-BR"
data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-today-highlignt="true" data-date-orientation="bottom" />
```